# Get specific text from html tag jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would I go about retrieving specific text from the HTML code? for example:

```
<a class="shopitem" data-minitooltip="item_123"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
```

How would I get *item_123* as text from that line using jquery?

Comment: `.data('minitooltip')`?

Comment: Use the `data()` function.  Did you do any prior research before asking your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use class selector on `shopitem` and use `data` method on that:

```js
console.log($('.shopitem').data('minitooltip'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="shopitem" data-minitooltip="item_123"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
```

You can also use `attr` method:

```js
console.log($('.shopitem').attr('data-minitooltip'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="shopitem" data-minitooltip="item_123"><img src="#" alt=""></a>
```